# ruby operator "=~"

Tags: ruby, operators

In ruby, I read some of the operators, but I couldn't find `=~`. What is `=~` for, or what does it mean? The program that I saw has

```
regexs = (/\d+/)
a = somestring
if a =~ regexs
```

I think it was comparing if `somestring` equal to digits but, is there any other usage, and what is the proper definition of the `=~` operator?

Comment: If you want to play around with Ruby regular expression I can recommend http://rubular.com/

Comment: Can we mark the other question as a duplicate, rather than this one? **This one has more votes**, in terms of both the question itself and the answers. Also, searching for `ruby =~ operator`, **this question is the first relevant hit** in Google, Yahoo, Bing, and DuckDuckGo in my tests, which also explains why this one has more votes.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The `=~` operator matches the regular expression against a string, and it returns either the offset of the match from the string if it is found, otherwise nil.

```
/mi/ =~ "hi mike" # => 3 
"hi mike" =~ /mi/ # => 3 

"mike" =~ /ruby/ # => nil
```

You can place the string/regex on either side of the operator as you can see above.

Answer (score 49):

This operator matches strings against regular expressions.

```
s = 'how now brown cow'

s =~ /cow/ # => 14
s =~ /now/ # => 4
s =~ /cat/ # => nil
```

If the String matches the expression, the operator returns the offset, and if it doesn't, it returns nil. It's slightly more complicated than that: [see documentation here; it's a method in the String class.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-7E)

Comment: Documentation is useless. Been searching for 45 minutes, this is the best explanation I've come across. Thank you.

Comment: Important point aka (NB): only works on strings not numbers.

Comment: Also, that it matches the "first substring" only as per the documentation: "Returns the Integer index of the first substring that matches the given regexp, or nil if no match found:"

Answer (score 18):

=~ is an operator for matching regular expressions, that will return the index of the start of the match (or nil if there is no match).

See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String._eq_sd) for the documentation.