# Ruby alphanumeric check

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to check that a variable `foo` in Ruby is non-empty and alphanumeric. I know I could iterate through each character and check, but is that a better way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Use Unicode or POSIX Character Classes

To validate that a string matches only alphanumeric text, you could use an anchored character class. For example:

```
# Use the Unicode class.
'foo' =~ /\A\p{Alnum}+\z/

# Use the POSIX class.
'foo' =~ /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/
```

#### Anchoring is Essential

The importance of anchoring your expression can't be overstated. Without anchoring, the following would *also* be true:

```
"\nfoo" =~ /\p{Alnum}+/
"!foo!" =~ /\p{Alnum}+/
```

which is unlikely to be what you expect.

Comment: +1 This takes into account all sorts of characters beyond `A-Za-z0-9`, which is a good thing.

Comment: What does the operator `=~` do? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @MikaH. It's the regular expression pattern match operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5781400/1301972 or http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html for more on this operator.

Comment: For an explaination about anchoring https://web.archive.org/web/20180813034209/https://batsov.com/articles/2013/12/04/regexp-anchors-in-ruby/