# How do \ / operator work in ruby Regular expression?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am using Ruby 1.9.3. Just going thorugh the Ruby tutorials. Now I just got stuck to a statement on which regular expression is working and giving out put also. But confusion with the `\/` operators logic.

***RegExp-1***

`Today's date is: 1/15/2013.` (String)

`(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})` (Expression)

***RegExp-2***

`s = 'a' * 25 + 'd' 'a' * 4 + 'c'` (String)

`/(b|a+)*\/ =~ s #=>` ( expression)

Now couldn't understand how `\/` and `=~` operator works in Ruby.

Could anyome out of here help me to understand the same?

Thanks

Comment: `\/` is for escaping the `/` otherwise it would close the expression early. Your last expression is invalid. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781362/ruby-operator for explaining the `=~` operator

Comment: You're asking a question that you could answer just by trying it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` serves as an escape character. In this context, it is used to indicate that the next character is a normal one and should not serve some special function.  normally the `/` would end the regex, as regex's are bookended by the `/`.  but preceding the `/` with a `\` basically says "i'm not telling you to end the regex when I use this `/`, i want that as part of the regex."

As Lee pointed out, your second regex is invalid, specifically because you never end the regex with a proper `/`.  you escape the last `/` so that it's just a plaintext character, so the regex is hanging.  it's like doing `str = "hello`.

as another example, normally `^` is used in regex to indicate the beginning of a string, but doing `\^` means you just want to use the `^` character in the regex.

`=~` says "does the regex match the string?" If there is a match, it returns the index of the start of the match, otherwise returns `nil`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781362/ruby-operator) for details.

**EDIT:** Note that the `?<month>`, `?<day>`, `?<year>` stuff is grouping.  seems like you could use a bit of brush-up on regex, check out [this appendix](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) of sorts to see what all the different special characters do.

Comment: Would you tell me what the output of this expression `(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})`?

Comment: there is no "ouput". it's just a regex (assuming you bookend it in `/`).

Comment: if you're trying to see how that regex matches the string you provided in the question, try it yourself! [rubular](http://rubular.com) is a great tool for ruby regex testing, or you can enter the ruby console and try matching the regex with the string using the =~ operator we discussed.

Comment: @DoLoveSky, Don't troll for up-votes. They will happen when people feel your contribution is worthy of it. Asking for them will irritate people causing the opposite result. Instead, contribute good, well thought-out and well-asked questions, and give solid concise answers and you'll gain votes.

Comment: @DoLoveSky, did you read the answer? It says "`If there is a match, it returns the index of the start of the match`".

Comment: Yes,I am now aware of that! When I asked , I was confused. After that I did some research and got the point!