# "If equal to a letter"

Tags: ruby, arrays, alphabetical

I am trying to write a method that takes in a string that will have no spaces. All I want it to do is to return "bug" when the character in the string is a letter `[A-Za-z]` and to return "ant" if it's any other character.

```
def Letter(str)
    (0..str.length).to_a do |index|
        if str[index].chr =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ##I think this is where things are going wrong.
            puts "bug"
        else
            puts "ant"
        end
    end
end
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I keep getting arrays of consecutive numbers.

Comment: `=~` [is the correct operator to compare against a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781362/ruby-operator), not the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: Still getting an array of numbers, but thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: To make your code work, you need to replace (1) `to_a` with `each` (2) `(0..str.length)` with either `(0..str.length-1)` or `(0...str.length)` (three dots) and (3) `str[index].chr` with `str[index]`. (2) is because, if `str = "cat"`, `(0..str.length) => (0..3)`, and when `index` gets to `3`, `str[3] => nil`, causing `"ant"` to be printed at the end, when it shouldn't be. @Amadan shows you the Ruby way to approach this problem. He also suggests some coding conventions to follow. I'll add one more: indent two spaces.

Comment: @the Tin Man Not homework. Just self practice. Plus I showed all my steps so let me know if I am not using proper etiquette and I will make sure to improve my question next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewritten

```
def letter(str)
  str.each_char.map do |char|
    (char =~ /[[:alpha:]]/) ? 'bug' : 'ant'
  end
end
```

In your code, you are trying to print "bug" or "ant"; but you're *returning* `(0..str.length).to_a`. This function will return an array of bugs and ants. It is also made more Rubyish:

- methods should be in snake_case (lowercase, with underscores between words)
- iterating over strings is easier with `each_char`
- it's fine with `[A-Za-z]`, but `[[:alpha:]]` is both clearer and handles Unicode stuff.
- since we're testing each character, you know it's going to be one character long, so you don't need the start of line and end of line anchors.

Answer (score -1):

```
def letter(str)
    str.chars.each do |x|
        puts x=~ /[A-Za-z]/ ? "bug" : "ant"
    end
end
```

- First things first, in your loop your are trying to convert a range
  into an array.

  (0..str.length).to_a

str.length returns a number, therefore making it into an array will give you an array of numbers. Hence your problem.

- Second, you have to have brackets around your `/a-zA-Z/` regex
- Third, use the ternary operator. It's great for small if statements. Heres the syntax:

  boolean ? "if boolean is true this code will execute" : "else this code will"
- Fourth, use the .each methods, ruby is loved partly because of the simplicity of loops and iterating!

Happy coding!

Comment: This won't work. `return` will immediately exit the method as soon as the ternary statement returns its value in the first iteration. `each` isn't going to iterate over the values of `str.chars` and *return* an array of "bug" and "ant" variables, it only iterates.

Comment: I was unsure if he wanted to only output "bug" once or for each iteration that matched the regex. My fault, I fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: No, that still won't work. `each` won't return what you think it will. Run your code in IRB and look at what's returned by the method.

Comment: You are correct, @theTinMan, however `.each` yields exactly what I think it will. I forgot to print it out over each iteration. Thanks!

Comment: Well, be careful with not answering the OP's question. The requirement is a method that *returns* the values.