# what does the instruction "name =~ /[A-Z].*/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm studying ruby ​​on rails and I'm seeing a code, but I could not understand how it actually works.

''''ruby

```
validate: first_letter_must_be_uppercase

private

def first_letter_must_be_uppercase

   errors.add ("name", "first letter must be uppercase") unless name =~ /[A-Z].*/

end
```

---

Comment: What's the specific question? Regarding regex? I'd recommend reading a regex tutorial/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do =~ and /\ mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938262/what-do-and-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is basically checking that the string should contain the first letter in the upper case using the regular expression

explanation:

```
/[A-Z].*/
```

- `[A-Z]` - Checks for any capital letter from A to Z
- `.` - checks for any wildcard character
- `*` - matches for 0 to any number of repetition.

To sum up

The input string should match the following format - A capital letter from A-Z and then should have 0 to any number of wildcard characters

You can check it on [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/iiu89xObtR7eSk)

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @vasfed if you want to match the first character the regex need to be changed to

```
/\A[A-Z].*/
```

`\A` - Ensure start of the string

Comment: to be precise - not first, but anywhere in string, regex does not have any anchors, probably it should have been `/\A[A-Z]/`